# Issue accessing local hosted Wordpress site (redirects+other nonsense)

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, mamp

I have ran into quite the issue.

I have been developing a website hosted locally with MAMP. I always used `localhost:90/wordpress/` to access the website and it was worked up till today. A few hours ago, I began the process of moving the website from local server to an actual domain. Unfortunately, I wasn't checking URLs and ended up changing some information and working on localhost `myPHPadmin` panel as opposed to the domain `myPHPadmin` panel. Long story short, I changed so much before I realized my mistake, then proceed to change even more, and now I am lost and don't know what to do. At this point, I am just trying to get access to my local hosted website so I can start over again.

**The issue:**
Everytime I goto `localhost:90/wordpress`, Chrome redirects me to `localhost/wordpress` and my website doesn't show, it says that the website can't be shown.

I have tried going into my local hosted `myPHPadmin` panel and changing `siteurl` and  `home` to both say `localhost`, but no luck. Interestingly, when I change both to `wordpress`, it shows an unformatted version of my homepage (Kinda like just straight HTML), with limited images, however if I click any links then it brings me to `wordpress/about` and it doesn't exist. If I change it to just `localhost:90`, it shows my unformatted wordpress `Page not found` page. Can't access `wp-admin` with any of them.

I have tried using a replace tool recommended in another thread, but searching for `localhost` and replacing with `localhost:90` yielded no results for me. I have also double checked the `.htaccess` folder and it is correct. I have cleared cookies/cache and still nothing. I am desperate.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First of all please try to access it in another browser or try clearing redirect cache in Chrome to be sure that this is not the browser who is playing with you
https://salferrarello.com/chrome-clear-redirect-cache/

Comment: @Owi Yes I have tried it in different browsers. Same thing occurs.

Comment: What were you changing in phpmyadmin and what were you changing it with? Did you have a look at your config.php to see if siteurl and homeurl are defined in the config.php? Make sure they are the same as your database siteurl and homeurl entries.

Comment: @HamzaAhmad In PHPmyadmin I was changing the wp_options siteurl and home values to the domain URL. I have since reverted those back to localhost (and I mention the results of changing it to different things above). Also, I was changing the wp-config.php file in root, specifically the define DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD and DB_SERVER fields, which have all since been reverted to correct ones. I am not quite sure what you are referencing with the siteurl and homeurl in the config.php, as I see nothing there. Unless I am looking at wrong file.

Comment: So everything you changed has been reverted back to how it was but you cannot access the site still?

Comment: @HamzaAhmad I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is here so I am going to shoot in the dark here and hopefully one of these methods will get you out of your predicament. Since you say that you have reverted all the changes you made and still your website is inaccessible, even `wp-admin`.

You can try doing the following:

Change the siteurl and homeurl links in your PHPmyadmin to `localhost:90/wordpress` or whatever it was before when your site was running and functional.

In your Wordpress root folder, there is a file called `wp-config.php`. Open that file and find:

```
* @package WordPress
*/
```

Add after:

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost:90/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost:90/wordpress');
```

You will replace all `localhost:90/wordpress` if need be by which I have written in my codes to what the link was before; when the site was functional.

Check the file thoroughly and through `Find/Replace` function of your favourite text editor for no duplicate entries.

Now try accessing `wp-admin`. If you still cannot access your `wp-admin`, take a backup of your current `wp-admin` folder.

From a fresh Wordpress of the same version as yours, copy the `wp-admin` folder and replace it with your current `wp-admin` folder. Now try to access `wp-admin` again.

If you are able to access it and login, refresh your Permalinks. See if your site is accessbile again after doing these steps.

Update:

Since none of those steps worked for you, try doing the following:

Delete all the Wordpress core files from your `localhost:90/wordpress` EXCEPT `wp-config.php` and your `wp-content` folder.

Now from a fresh Wordpress folder, copy the files and folders EXCEPT `wp-config.php` file and `wp-content` folder. Paste them in your `localhost:90/wordpress` folder.

Try accessing your website now.

Update 2:

Try uploading your Wordpress to your online server and change the values of `siteurl` and `homeurl` in your `wp-config.php` file. We defined the localhost addresses in the file, now you will update those with your domain details.

Take a fresh backup of your database from your localhost and import it into a new database in your online server. Update the `homeurl` and `siteurl` in your newly imported database.

Update your `wp-config.php` with the new database name and username and password of the account you have given all privilages to access the database.

Try accessing `wp-admin` now.

If successful, update your Permalinks and then try accessing your website.

This will tell us if your localhost is faulty.

Comment: I have done what you said, sadly same result. When everything (wp-config+wp_options) are set to localhost:90, I am able to connect to the website, but it tells me page not found. Link below shows exactly what it looks like. This occurs for any link I try (even wp-admin, or clicking the pages it has listed)

https://imgur.com/a/Ici95qv


Is there any way I can do a fresh install of WP, but copy over the content and formatting of my previous website? That is what I am mainly interested in at this point.

Comment: @IBeDubya I have updated my answer. Check it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: I would like to thank you for being with me and helping me with this. Sadly, I have tried your newest update and still have the same issue. It looks exactly like the picture I provided earlier. No pages, or wp-admin work. I feel like we are getting closer though! Anymore suggestions?

Comment: @IBeDubya Check update 2 in my answer, see if it works for you.